# Django display user form validation error message when inherited from UserAdmin

Tags: python, django

I am using the django User model with profile to extend the User with few more attributes. I require to ensure unique email id across the users in the User table.

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm 
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class UserForm(UserAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"

    readonly_fields = ('date_joined',)

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'Email addresses must be unique.')
        return email
```

This validation message is not displayed in the User form.

The custom user admin is defined as

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    def save(UserForm, commit=True):
        return super(UserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Email already exists ya"),
                                        code='invalid')

    inlines = (ProfileInline, )

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

This validation message is seen in the traceback in debug mode and not in the UserForm.

Require the message to show the error in the UserForm. I understand that there are 2 forms viz. 
UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm  in the  django auth.

Using django 3.0, python 3.7

Answer (score 6):

You should use clean method in Model class instead.
Add this code into your User(you should customize auth's User model) in models.py.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class User(AbstractUser):
    # add clean method here
    def clean(self):
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise ValidationError(_("Email already exists ya"), code='invalid')
```

This method is for validating field of model.

Answer (score 0):

If I where you I would put a unique = True on the email field on your user model. Django will then take care of the rest, no custom form validation necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using clean_email, try using clean . Ex:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm 
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class UserForm(UserAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"

    readonly_fields = ('date_joined',)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        email = cleaned_data.get('email')
        if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'Email addresses must be unique.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom validator and provide it as "validators" argument in the Field Creation.

Here is the custom validator:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
def email_validator(email):
    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        raise ValidationError("Email already exists ya", code='invalid')
```

And then in the User model's email field just provide this email_validator in the validators argument as below:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    # other fields
    email = models.EmailField("email", unique=True, validators=[email_validator])
```

Django will use your custom validator and it will show the error right below the field on the User Creation Form.